# How do I convert SVG image into Bytes in dart and how to again decode that bytes List

Tags: flutter, dart, watermark

final watermarkBytes = (await rootBundle.load(SVG Image)).buffer.asUint8List();

Again, I need to convert these watermarkBytes to Image Data Type.

```dart
_applyWaterMark({watermarkImage,lookbookImageUrl}) async{
    final watermarkBytes = (await rootBundle.load(watermarkImage)) .buffer.asUint8List();
    var img = await rootBundle.load(watermarkImage);
    var decodedImage = await decodeImageFromList(img.buffer.asUint8List());
    var watermarkRatio = decodedImage.width / decodedImage.height;
    Image image = Image.network(lookbookImageUrl); // to get heigth and width of imageurl
    ImageInfo info = await getImageInfo(image);
   
    Uint8List? imgData = await Matting.getImageData(lookbookImageUrl);
    final bytes = imgData;

    /// [distY] is the vertical gap between the lookbook image edges and watermark edges;
    /// [distX] is the horizontal gap between the lookbook image edges and watermark edges;
    int distY = 0, distX = 0;

    /// setting [distX], [distY] values based on the min. values of lookbook image's width and height;
    if(info.image.width < info.image.height){ 
       distY =  info.image.height - decodedImage.height - ((2/100)*info.image.width).toInt();
      distX =  info.image.width - decodedImage.width - ((2/100)*info.image.width).toInt();
    }
    else {
      distY = distX = info.image.height - decodedImage.height - ((2/100)*info.image.height).toInt();
      distX = distX = info.image.width - decodedImage.width - ((2/100)*info.image.height).toInt();

    }
    var watermarkedImg = await image_watermark.addImageWatermark(imgData!, watermarkBytes,
      imgHeight: (((decodedImage.width/watermarkRatio)/100)*info.image.height).toInt(), imgWidth: ((25/100)*info.image.width).toInt(), 
      dstY: distY, dstX: distX
    );
    return watermarkedImg;
}

// invoking a function
 var afterWaterMarkedImage = await _applyWaterMark(watermarkImage: 'assets/images/imgLookbookWatermark.svg',lookbookImageUrl: imageurl); // imageurl is getting from API
```

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: actually I need to convert SVG image into Bytes again I need to convert that Bytes into Image data type.
But I'm facing this issue.

```dart
Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'Input contained an error.
```